# Apple Pay works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I am able to display Apple Pay view controller on simulator but not on device.

Entitlement added and certificate installed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {

var paymentRequest: PKPaymentRequest! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func rydes(shipping: Double) -> [PKPaymentSummaryItem] {

    let ryde = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Your Fare", amount: 1.00)
    let discount = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Discount", amount: -0.00)
    let shipping = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Shipping", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(shipping)"))
    let subTotal = ryde.amount.adding(discount.amount)
    let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "rydes", amount: subTotal)

    return [ryde, discount, shipping, total]

} // rydes() func


    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didSelect shippingMethod: PKShippingMethod, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus, [PKPaymentSummaryItem]) -> Void) {

        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success, rydes(shipping: Double(shippingMethod.amount)))

    } // paymentAuthorizationViewController( didSelectShippingMethod )



    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success)

    } // paymentAuthorizationViewController( didAuthorizePayment )



    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } // paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish()


@IBAction func applePayPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    print("enable apple pay")

    // send user to Apple Pay to make payment

    let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.visa, .masterCard, .interac, .discover, .amex]
    let merchantId = "merchant.com.xxx"


    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {

        paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "CAD"
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "CA"
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = merchantId
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.all]
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = self.rydes(shipping: 0.00)

        // . . .  shipping - not really needed

        let samedayShipping = PKShippingMethod(label: "Same Day", amount: 12.99)
        samedayShipping.detail = "Guaranteed same day delivery."
        samedayShipping.identifier = "sameday"

        let twodayShipping = PKShippingMethod(label: "Two Day", amount: 4.99)
        twodayShipping.detail = "Guaranteed within two days."
        twodayShipping.identifier = "twoday"

        let freeShipping = PKShippingMethod(label: "Same Day", amount: 0.00)
        freeShipping.detail = "Guaranteed same day."
        freeShipping.identifier = "freeShipping"

        paymentRequest.shippingMethods = [samedayShipping, twodayShipping, freeShipping]

        // . . .  shipping - not really needed

        let applePayVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        applePayVC.delegate = self
        self.present(applePayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }  else {

        print("Tell the user they need to set up Apple Pay!")
    }

} // applePayPressed func ACTION

}
```

The above code just returns this line - Tell the user they need to set up Apple Pay!

I am using a iPhone 6s as the device and Apple Pay and Wallet are enabled with a valid debit card and credit card.  I am from Canada, so I am in a valid region.

### Edited Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {

var paymentRequest: PKPaymentRequest! // apple pay

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func rydes() -> [PKPaymentSummaryItem] {

    let ryde = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Your Fare", amount: 1.00)
    let subTotal = ryde.amount
    let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "rydes", amount: subTotal)

    return [ryde, total]

} // rydes() func



    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success)

    } // paymentAuthorizationViewController( didAuthorizePayment )



    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } // paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish()


@IBAction func applePayPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    print("enable apple pay")

    // send user to Apple Pay to make payment

    let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.visa, .masterCard, .interac, .discover, .amex]
    let merchantID = "merchant.com.xxx"

    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
        paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "CAD"
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "CA"
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = merchantID
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.all]
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = self.rydes()

        let applePayVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        applePayVC.delegate = self
        self.present(applePayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }  else {

        print("Tell the user they need to set up Apple Pay!")
    }

} // applePayPressed func ACTION

}
```

[image: entitlements]

[image: console print]

Comment: how about  it may be restricted by parental control ?

Comment: I checked and all restrictions are off!

Comment: You have a missing quote on: `let merchantId = merchant.com.xxx"   <---- is not matched by a beginning one.`  Should be: `let merchantId = "merchant.com.xxx"`. Edit: I fixed it.

Comment: @Brandon I just put that in there as to not show my merchant ID. - thanks for updating :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue I face during enable of Apple Pay to my application. Make sure you have entered all the valid shipping, service and total payment value inside PKPayment​Summary​Item.

**Also total payment value should be greater that 0.0 to show the payment gate way view. If any of the value is 0.0 then don't add as SummaryItem.**

Code for Valid PKPaymentSummaryItem:

```
{
// 12.75 subtotal
NSDecimalNumber *subtotalAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1275
 exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];
self.subtotal = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Subtotal" amount:subtotalAmount];

// 2.00 discount
NSDecimalNumber *discountAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:200 exponent:-2 isNegative:YES];
self.discount = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Discount" amount:discountAmount];

// 12.75 - 2.00 = 10.75 grand total
NSDecimalNumber *totalAmount = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
totalAmount = [totalAmount decimalNumberByAdding:subtotalAmount];
totalAmount = [totalAmount decimalNumberByAdding:discountAmount];
self.total = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"My Company Name" amount:totalAmount];
self.summaryItems = @[self.subtotal, self.discount, self.total];
request.paymentSummaryItems = self.summaryItems;
}
```

This will try to fix your above issue.

**Edit:**
Just remove below code and check it again or put check condition if value for discount or shipping is greater that 0.0 then you can send shipping and discount as summary item:

```
    let ryde = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Your Fare", amount: 1.00)
//change some value here:
    let discount = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Discount", amount: -0.00)
    let shipping = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Shipping", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(shipping)"))
Make sure your subtotal or total is greater that 0.0.
    let subTotal = ryde.amount.adding(discount.amount)
    let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "rydes", amount: subTotal)
```

Comment: I don't know Objective-C very well, can you put this in Swift 3?

Comment: No luck :/. I removed all discounts and shipping as I don't use them and still no luck.  Revised code in Edit.

Comment: I found the problem, besides the shipping and discounts, I decided to add my visa to my wallet, along with Interac Debit, and it worked.  When I look at the cards, it says that Debit Card is not available for in app payments.  Any idea why?

Comment: Hii @LizG did you solve the problem? I have same error? i implemented apple pay with stripe using swift. I run the program it is works well in simulators but not in real iphone device?In real device it doesn't show the paymentsheet. Why ? do you know the reason please help me.

Comment: To test apple pay in real device can we add test cards to our wallet?Then only is it work in real device

Answer (score 0):

**If you can see the apple pay option on your simulator and are confused about why it is not showing on a real device, then this answer is for you.**

Initially, you may not see the apple pay option on real devices because you may not have any cards added to the Wallet app.

In this case, you have to follow [Apple Pay - Sandbox Testing - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/) and set up a sandbox account to test apple pay.

Steps:

1. Go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/testers and add your tester account. Use a fresh email address that was not used with any Apple services.
2. From your iPhone, go to settings, sign out from your logged-in Apple ID, and log in to your new tester account.
3. Select your region, where apple pay is available. E.j. United States  (If not already)
4. Open the Wallet application and add a new card.

> Name: Any
> Card Number: 3499 569590 41362
> Security Code: 1111
> Expiration Date: 12/2022

5. When successfully card added open your iOS app and you can see apple pay now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a card added to your Apple Pay wallet on the device you are testing with :) Simple, but was the fix for me.